# Pandas: Most efficient way to make dictionary of dictionaries from DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, hash, machine-learning, dataframe

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

labels = ["c1","c2","c3"]
c1 = ["one","one","one","two","two","three","three","three","three"]
c2 = [random.random() for i in range(len(c1))]
c3 = ["alpha","beta","gamma","alpha","gamma","alpha","beta","gamma","zeta"]
DF = pd.DataFrame(np.array([c1,c2,c3])).T
DF.columns = labels
```

DataFrame looks like:

```
      c1               c2     c3
0    one   0.440958516531  alpha
1    one   0.476439953723   beta
2    one   0.254235673552  gamma
3    two   0.882724336464  alpha
4    two    0.79817899139  gamma
5  three   0.677464637887  alpha
6  three   0.292927670096   beta
7  three  0.0971956881825  gamma
8  three   0.993934915508   zeta
```

The only way I could think of making the dictionary was to:

```
D_greek_value = {}

for greek in set(DF["c3"]):
    D_c1_c2 = {}
    for i in range(DF.shape[0]):
        row = DF.iloc[i,:]
        if row[2] == greek:
            D_c1_c2[row[0]] = row[1]
    D_greek_value[greek] = D_c1_c2
D_greek_value
```

The resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
{'alpha': {'one': '0.67919712421',
  'three': '0.67171020684',
  'two': '0.571150669821'},
 'beta': {'one': '0.895090207979', 'three': '0.489490074662'},
 'gamma': {'one': '0.964777504708',
  'three': '0.134397632659',
  'two': '0.10302290374'},
 'zeta': {'three': '0.0204226923557'}}
```

I don't want to assume c1 will come in blocks ("one" being together everytime).  I'm doing this on a csv that is a few hundred MB and I feel like I'm doing it all wrong. Please help if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you could take advantage of `groupby` to handle most of the work:

```
>>> result = df.groupby("c3")[["c1","c2"]].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values)).to_dict()
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'alpha': {'one': 0.440958516531,
           'three': 0.677464637887,
           'two': 0.8827243364640001},
 'beta': {'one': 0.47643995372299996, 'three': 0.29292767009599996},
 'gamma': {'one': 0.254235673552,
           'three': 0.0971956881825,
           'two': 0.79817899139},
 'zeta': {'three': 0.993934915508}}
```

---

Some explanation: first we group by c3, and select the columns c1 and c2.  This gives us the groups we want to turn into dictionaries:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby("c3")[["c1", "c2"]]
>>> grouped.apply(lambda x: print(x,"\n","--")) # just for display purposes
      c1                   c2
0    one    0.679926178687387
3    two  0.11495090934413166
5  three   0.7458197179794177 
 --
      c1                   c2
0    one    0.679926178687387
3    two  0.11495090934413166
5  three   0.7458197179794177 
 --
      c1                   c2
1    one  0.12943266757277916
6  three  0.28944292691097817 
 --
      c1                   c2
2    one  0.36642834809341274
4    two   0.5690944224514624
7  three   0.7018221838129789 
 --
      c1                  c2
8  three  0.7195852795555373 
 --
```

Given any of these subframes, say the next-to-last, we need to come up with a way to turn it into a dictionary.  For example:

```
>>> d3
      c1        c2
2    one  0.366428
4    two  0.569094
7  three  0.701822
```

If we try `dict` or `to_dict`, we don't get what we want because the indices and column labels get in the way:

```
>>> dict(d3)
{'c1': 2      one
4      two
7    three
Name: c1, dtype: object, 'c2': 2    0.366428
4    0.569094
7    0.701822
Name: c2, dtype: float64}
>>> d3.to_dict()
{'c1': {2: 'one', 4: 'two', 7: 'three'}, 'c2': {2: 0.36642834809341279, 4: 0.56909442245146236, 7: 0.70182218381297889}}
```

But we can ignore this by dropping down to the underlying data with `.values`, and then that can be passed into `dict`:

```
>>> d3.values
array([['one', 0.3664283480934128],
       ['two', 0.5690944224514624],
       ['three', 0.7018221838129789]], dtype=object)
>>> dict(d3.values)
{'three': 0.7018221838129789, 'one': 0.3664283480934128, 'two': 0.5690944224514624}
```

So if we apply this we get a Series with the indices as the c3 keys we want and the values as dictionaries, and that we can turn into a dictionary using `.to_dict()`:

```
>>> result = df.groupby("c3")[["c1", "c2"]].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))
>>> result
c3
alpha    {'three': '0.7458197179794177', 'one': '0.6799...
beta     {'one': '0.12943266757277916', 'three': '0.289...
gamma    {'three': '0.7018221838129789', 'one': '0.3664...
zeta                       {'three': '0.7195852795555373'}
dtype: object
>>> result.to_dict()
{'zeta': {'three': '0.7195852795555373'}, 'gamma': {'three': '0.7018221838129789', 'one': '0.36642834809341274', 'two': '0.5690944224514624'}, 'beta': {'one': '0.12943266757277916', 'three': '0.28944292691097817'}, 'alpha': {'three': '0.7458197179794177', 'one': '0.679926178687387', 'two': '0.11495090934413166'}}
```

Comment: Very nice.  I wonder if this is faster than what I posted.  I would expect `groupby` to be very fast but it's possible the lambda will slow it down.  I'm too lazy to time it though.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: me too. :-)  I tried to see if I could get the same result using only vectorized ops but bounced; someone else may have something more clever.  But I think you've already put your finger on the big problem (too many iterations) and everything beyond that is minor by comparison..

Comment: @DSM I know how to use lambda functions for sorting but exactly is happening from ".apply" to ".to_dict()"?

Comment: @O.rka: I added some explanation, breaking it down step-by-step.

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating multiple times over your data frame for each unique greek letter.  It's better to iterate just once.

Since you need a dictionary of dictionaries, you could use a `collections.defaultdict` with `dict` as the default constructor of the nested dicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
for dx, num_word, val, greek in DF.itertuples():
    result[greek][num_word] = val
```

Or use a regular dictionary and a call to `setdefault` to create the nested dict.

```
result = {}
for dx, num_word, val, greek in DF.itertuples():
    result.setdefault(greek, {})[num_word] = val
```